# How to keep pygame screen in the foreground?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a python program. I am using `pygame` to create the window and capturing the keyboard events.
But when I use other applications my `pygame window` goes into background and unless I bring back to the foreground it doesn't capture my keyboard inputs.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                print("Take screenshot..")
        if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this easily in pygame 1.x. AFAIK pygame 2.x will support this as SDL 2 introduced the `SDL_WINDOW_ALWAYS_ON_TOP` flag.

If you're on windows I guess you could use the win32-API to get the handle of your window and call [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with the `HWND_TOPMOST` flag.